# Using h3 tag in place of spree logo makes formatting go awry

Tags: css, spree, partials, deface

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/layouts/admin",
    :name => "backend_logo",
    :replace      => 'erb[loud]:contains("spree/admin/shared/header")',
    :partial => "layouts/backend_navbar")
```

I made a partial in layouts by copying the one on GitHub that matches the build (stable 3) of Spree I am using but replaced the Logo with an `h3` heading.

It works, the heading comes up but the rest (`sidebar-toggle` and `admin_login_navigation_bar`) are no longer inline. `sidebar-toggle` is sitting under the sidebar and `admin_login_navigation_bar` has disappeared.

I thought it might be the CSS so I gave the `h3` tag the same id and class as the image tag, as you can see below on either side of `<h3>Boogie</h3>`. I know there's probably a better way, like an override that just replaces the logo. I did that for the frontend but couldn't get it to work for the backend. Now I've played with this one so long that I'd really like to know what gives in this case.

```
<% admin = try_spree_current_user.try(:has_spree_role?, "admin") %>
<header class="header <%= admin ? "logged-in" : "logged-out" %>">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="navbar-header col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                    <h3 id="logo" class: "logo navbar-brand">Boogie</h3>
                    <% if admin %>
                        <span class="navbar-toggle" id="sidebar-toggle">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </span>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
                <% if admin %>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                        <div class="navbar-right" data-hook="admin_login_navigation_bar"></div>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```